# Starting a runnable in background thread

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable

I have, to my knowledge, implemented a runnable which is created on a new thread. However, the thread does not seem to be running in the background, and the actions taken inside the runnable are stalling the UI with heavy actions.

See below:

```
custListLoadThread = new Thread(loadRunnable);
custListLoadThread.run();

private Runnable loadRunnable = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);

        Gen.popup("TEST"); // Creates a toast pop-up.
        // This is to know if this runnable is running on UI thread or not!

        try
        {               
            customers = Db.BasicArrays.getCustomers(CustomApp.Session.businessCode, empId);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    populate();
                    setCustListVisible(true);
                    loading = false;
                }
            });
        }
        catch (final Exception ex)
        {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Gen.popup(ex.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

However this code does not run in the background, it still seems to run on the UI thread. I have placed the line `Gen.popup("TEST");` to make sure of this (calling a `toast` pop up in a non-UI thread should cause an error).

Any ideas as to why this runnable isn't running in the background?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
custListLoadThread = new Thread(loadRunnable);
custListLoadThread.start();
```

You need to start the thread, not call the run() method in the current thread.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks very much! Got caught out by the similarities of `run` and `start`!

Answer (score 16):

If you want to execute code on a background thread that does not do something with the UI:

```
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //your action
        }
    };
    AsyncTask.execute(runnable);
```

Of course as written before you can also create a new thread (that is independent from the UI thread):

```
    new Thread(runnable).start();
```

In your example you want to update UI elements, so better use a `AsyncTask` (must be called from UI thread!):

```
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // your async action
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            // update the UI (this is executed on UI thread)
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }.execute();
```